# Adding custom cell via NIB in UICollecitonView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nib

I have a very simple swift program using a custom cell built with a Nib in a UICollectionView.

When I run the application I get an error stating

> :Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:"

I've looked at all the tutorials and have followed them exactly, it looks like I'm missing an initializer somehow but I'm at a loss. In the main default cell in the CollectionViewController in the storyboard editor I named the reuse identifier "Cell", for the Nib (swift file is named CustomCollectionViewCell.xib) I named the reuse identifier "CustomCell". I have a single UIButton in the Xib as an action which should log success if pressed.

Here is the mainVC:

```
class MainCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false


    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell

    return cell
}
}
```

Here is the CustomCollectionViewCell code:

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


@IBAction func testButton(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Success!")
}
```

}

I know this is a basic, beginner item but I've looked everywhere on the web and am stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to add I do define let reuseIdentifier = "Cell" in the main VC above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use prototype cells. Change the class of the prototype cell to CustomCollectionViewCell, setup your UI in that cell. Delete:

```
self.collectionView!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

In viewDidLoad and delete CustomCollectionViewCell.xib

Comment: I had that working, but I want to be able to have different cells within the collection view, each with their own UI items (i.e. one may have a UISwitch another may have a UISlider), I don't know how to do that other than unique XIB files.

Comment: You can have multiple prototype cells with different cell identifiers and different subclasses of UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: I got it working using multiple prototype cells, much easier than using xib's. I'm still curious why the above code didn't work.

Comment: I think you had your identifiers wrong. I believe you need to not have any prototype cells in your tableview, then register your nibs with unique ids.

Comment: That was it! I eliminated the proto cell and everything worked.